# How to build SQL Relay for PDO from source on windows?

Tags: php, pdo, php-extension

I am trying to integrate SQL Relay with PHP PDO on Windows (WAMP). I have installed and compiled Rudiments and SQL Relay on Windows through Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt following the instructions given on the [Rudiments](http://rudiments.sourceforge.net/rudiments/installing.html) and [SQL Relay](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/admin/installing.html) SourceForge pages.

Then I downloaded the `pdo_sqlrelay` extension source from github and tried to build the dll for this extension.

In the build instructions, I couldn't find the ones pertaining to Windows specifically. I found instructions related to Linux. They are:

```
cd /path/to/pdo_sqlrelay
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/php-config \
--with-pdo-sqlrelay=/path/to/sqlrelay/prefix \
--with-rudiments=/path/to/rudiments/prefix

make
make install
```

I tried to convert them to the relative Windows commands by following the step by step php extension build instructions on [PHP's Wiki for building for Windows](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).

When I tried to execute the command, it threw a `fatal error`. (like `undefined` or `invalid $remains`).:

```
configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-$remains
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me out to build the `pdo_sqlrelay` extension on Windows.

Comment: This documentation doesn't contains the source to download php_pdo_sqlrelay.dll or to build phppdo extension for sql relay..

Comment: voted up for you then, I misunderstood, good luck though

Comment: How do you execute the command `configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-$remains`?

Comment: I am trying to execute it through Developer command prompt on windows as mentioned in the doc but it is throwing up errors. Could you recommend a way to execute it...

Comment: $remains looks like a bash variable that didn't get set, but the docs don't even attempt to outline what that variable should be exported as...

Comment: My guess is that $remains is just an example there ie. --enable-phpdbg/--enable-soap etc. anything. Seems like you're supposed to put the extension you want enabled, not *literally* $remains.

Comment: Correct.. $remains is an example. But I am wondering which extension do we need to replace here so as to make it working on windows.

Comment: [This](http://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/build-php-extension-on-windows/) might be a useful resource on the matter.

Comment: Have you tried `configure --help`? Seems you recognize it is just example/placeholder. So why would you expect that would work?

Comment: When you build php from the source, you can enable features and libraries with the --enable-* parameter, you can propably just omit the whole command there and add what you need enabled for the sql relay and rudiments. Might be as simple as `configure` depending what you got

Answer (score 1):

you need to ...

first run `bin\phpsdk_setvars.bat`

to set up the build environment, so that `$remains` will be known as a variable.

then configure the build with `buildconf` (or `buildconf --force` for rebuilding).

then `configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-$remains` ... you probably might also want to `--disable-zts` (depending which PHP is being used).

it's rather `nmake` to build & `nmake clean` to clean.

to install & uninstall it's `nmake install` and `nmake uninstall`.

the documentation also states ...that:

> **First** build and install [Rudiments](http://rudiments.sourceforge.net/rudiments/installing.html), **then** build and install [SQL Relay](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/admin/installing.html).